# Exit code from C++ Builder Windowed (GUI) win32 application

Tags: c++builder

I can't seem to find how to exit a (non console) Windowed application with a value.  I was hoping this is a value I can set via `TApplication`, but not the case (that I can see).

I assume setting errorlevel via `SetEnvironmentVariable()` is futile, since on exit the program will overwrite this value (Not tested tbh)

The idea is to test this return value in a batch file via `errorlevel`

Following should be able to do that in the batch:

```
start /wait something.exe
echo %errorlevel%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

- make your app's `WinMain()` function (found in your project's main `.cpp` file) return whatever value you want.
- set the RTL's [global `ExitCode` variable](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.ExitCode) that is declared in `System.hpp`.

Comment: Thanks Remy,  I tried `System::ExitCode = 911 ;` which compiles but does nothing in terms of errorlevel.  Perhaps because WinMain() appears to be returning 0 already in the code.  When I change the latter value it works. I will work with that.  Thanks.

Comment: Then simply have `WinMain()` return `ExitCode` instead of `0`, then you can change `ExitCode` whenever and wherever you want.

Comment: Strange `return System::ExitCode;` returns `0`.  Yet in debug mode I can see ExitCode has the proper value I set before.  `return 666;` returns 666 fine.

Comment: The plot thickens.  When I set `System::ExitCode` to whatever code just before I call `return System::ExitCode ;`  the proper, just set code, is properly returned.  The debugger reported value aside, something clears ExitCode before it is returned.  I'll figure it out.

Comment: `ExitCode` is just an `int` variable in global memory. It is not possible for `return System::ExitCode;` to return 0 if `ExitCode` is not 0. Nothing clears `ExitCode` on return from `WinMain()`. I suggest you put a data breakpoint on `ExitCode` at program startup and check if maybe some other thread is updating `ExitCode` when you are not expecting it.

Comment: It was the `ShellExecuteEx()` of itself with elevated rights that messed with things.  I didn't realize that the program would behave differently when ran from a batch file in CMD.  It doesn't do this in normal operation (on my system)  I thought that my Windows settings also applied to the CMD.